# app.configure(function){} typeerror undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

i am creating a chat application using socket.io and angularjs, when i run the app.js file using cmd, i get an error saying "app.configure(function){} typeerror undefined is not a function"
what could be the problem?

my code looks like this:

```
  var http = require('http');
  var express = require('express'),
   routes = require('./routes'),
   socket = require('./routes/socket.js');
      app = module.exports.app = express();
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server                      instance
   server.listen(80);
```

// Configuration

```
  app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {
   layout: false
   });
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(express.methodOverride());
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(app.router);
      });
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what version of Express are you using?
Since Express 4.x there is no app.configure() - http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#other-changes ``app.configure() has been removed. Use process.env.NODE_ENV or app.get('env') to detect the environment and configure the app accordingly.`` Also it helps if you provide full stack trace next time.

Comment: make this line  app = module.exports.app = express() to app = express() and see if it works

Answer (score 12):

i was using Express 4.0 in which configure was removed. See http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#other-changes
Simple mistake took me an hour to realise.

Comment: What's the solution here to support the equivalent of the configure() function ?

Comment: just call app.use directly